# how can I make my PC mouse cursor continue from where it left off, controlled through Android phone?

Tags: android, cursor, mapping, mouse, coordinates

I am able to control my PC mouse with my Android phone. I would like the mouse cursor to continue its motion from where it left off. Just like a regular mouse. When I continue to move my finger across the phone's screen, the mouse should keep moving forward and same goes for other directions.

To give you an example:
Say I move the cursor to 40, 50 which translates to PCs 400, 500. Now when I put my finger on the device at say 10, 5 the cursor on PC will jump to 100, 50! But I want it to continue from 400, 500.

I am making these numbers up. But the phone's coordinates are converted to PC's like this:

```
PC_COORDS = MOBILE_COORDS * FACTOR;
where FACTOR = PC_MAX_DIMENSION / MOBILE_MAX_DIMENSION;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking for some logic interpretation, maybe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
PC_COORDS = getCurrentPcCoords() + ( MOBILE_COORDS * FACTOR );
```

Of course `getCurrentPcCoords()` is not a real function, just to fill the idea behind the example.

Keep in mind that this will ADD the new coordinates, so what you might actually want is to get the 'change of the movement' in the android device and multiply that by the factor then add it to the current coordinates of the PC.

Comment: but wouldn't PC_COORDS keep growing with this? So if i understand correctly you mean something like delta_coords = ( ( prev_mobile_coords - curr_mobile_coords ) * factor ) + getCurrPcCoords();

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by 'change of the movement', note: `delta = final - initial` so `delta = curr - prev`. The way you have it, your pointer will be moving in the opposite direction, you can just reverse the sign. // Again, this is all from an abstract point of view, when it comes to the actual coding and exactly what functions to call, I wont be able to help. But abstractly and theoretically, I can put it some thoughts :D Let me know what happens, I am interested.

Comment: yea sure i am gonna give it a try once i get home.

Comment: didn't work as expected. the cursor keeps jumping and does not continue from its last position.

Comment: You sure you put the function right? `PC_COORDS = getCurrentPcCoords() + ( (getCurrentMobileCoords() - getPreviouseMobileCoords()) * FACTOR );` Just make sure to do the correct order of operations.